# PHP Inline If Syntax error

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm trying to make a inline if request.

Here the code

```
<?=(file_exits($storage.$file.'.md5')) ? file_get_contents($storage.$file.'.md5') : file_put_contents($storage.$file.'.md5', md5_file($storage.$file)?>
```

The log says

```
syntax error, unexpected '?>', expecting ',' or ')'
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Count number of `)`

Comment: you forgot a `)` at the end

Comment: This shouldn't be a ternary in the first place. If the file does not exist, you're going to output the result of `file_put_contents`…?!

Comment: 9 xD Thank you very much

Comment: I'm surprised it didn't fall over at `file_exits` tbh.

Comment: @CD001 That's because it never got that far because it failed in the parsing stage, before runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've missed a closing bracket `)` in the end, just before the `?>`

Here is a fixed code:

```
<?=(file_exits($storage.$file.'.md5')) ? file_get_contents($storage.$file.'.md5') : file_put_contents($storage.$file.'.md5', md5_file($storage.$file))?>
```